# deleting a row in parse server?

Tags: java, android, parse-server

the problem is the list item on which it is clicked does not get deleted but an item behind or in front of it gets deleted (for list2.get(d) or list2.get(d-1))how to get the item which is clicked to get deleted?)

```
 Intent intent=getIntent();
    k=intent.getStringExtra("this is a");
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            d=i;
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(Main3Activity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("this is a");
            dialog.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int l){
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> b=new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("message");
                    b.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e)
                        {
                            if(e==null) {
                                for (ParseObject n : objects) {
                                    if (n.getString("message").equals(list2.get(d))&&(n.getString("receiver").equals(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername().toString())&&n.getString("sender").equals(k)))
                                    {
                                        try {
                                            Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this,list2.get(d+1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            n.delete();
                                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                                            e1.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Log.i("this is a",e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    list2.remove(d);
                    a.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in this case refers to onItemClickListener context. You can either use application context by calling `getApplicationContext()` OR if you need local context, use `CLASSNAME.this`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
Intent intent=getIntent();
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());

    }
});
```

OR

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
Intent intent=getIntent();
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    }
});
```